# AJAX get request does not recognize submitted data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the following code ran on the client-side to access the properties of a user within the database.

```
firebaseAUTH.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user) {
console.log('user has signed in with e-mail address: '+user.email+' and user ID: '+user.uid)
firebaseAUTH.currentUser.getToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
$.ajax(
    {
// Send token to your backend via HTTPS (JWT)
      url: '/auth',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {token: idToken},
      success: function (response){
      var userID = response.userID
  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var industry = snapshot.val().industry
  var company = snapshot.val().company
  var firstname = snapshot.val().firstname
  var email = snapshot.val().email
  var source = snapshot.val().source
  var phone = snapshot.val().phone
  var password = snapshot.val().password
  var lastname = snapshot.val().lastname
      $.get(
        {
          url: '/members-area/'+userID,
          data: {userID: userID,
                industry: industry,
                email: email},
          success: function(response){
          window.location = '/members-area/'+userID
          }
      })
```

My server-side code:

```
app.get('/members-area/:userID', function(req,res,next) {
  res.render('members-area', { userID: req.params.userID, industry: req.params.industry, email: req.params.email})                                                                  
})
```

However, when I try to access the 'industry' variable in pug, it shows undefined. As you can see I send it above within the GET ajax call so what is the problem? It's also weird because I logged to the console the variables names'right after the function snapshot and they were there. Also, mysteriously 'userID' shows up as a var with content but 'industry' and 'email' do not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite know what you're trying to do but hopefully I can help some.

First off you don't need a second call to get the token. When you call signInWithEmailAndPassword firebase returns the user. So you can call getToken right away

```
firebaseAUTH.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user) {
console.log('user has signed in with e-mail address: '+user.email+' and user ID: '+user.uid)
console.log('we also got the token: ' + user.getToken());
...
```

You also seem to be posting to a route that isn't defined, and then you query a different route with get.

> Also, mysteriously 'userID' shows up as a var with content but
>   'industry' and 'email' do not at all.

In your server side code your route is only defined with one parameter: userID. The line

```
app.get('/members-area/:userID', function(req,res,next)
```

Defines userID as a parameter, not the other 2 variables. So it makes sense that they're undefined.

What I think you're trying to do is:

```
firebaseAUTH.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user) {
    const userId = user.getToken();
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        $.post('/members-area/' + userId, snapshot.val(), function(data, status) {
           console.log(data);
           console.log(status);
    });
});
```

And then in your server code:

```
app.post('/members-area/:userID', function(req,res,next) {
  const theSnapshot = req.body;
  res.send(theSnapshot)
});
```

I still don't understand why you would want to retrive information using client code from a database and then post it a server only to get it again. But maybe I am misunderstanding something :)

Its also very strange to see a get request that sends data, I'm pretty sure its against the specs. You usually want to use post to send data and then use get to ehm get the data :)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Am I supposed to use post or get for a private/protected page, i.e. is there any convention for that? I thought it would be GET as that makes sense: loading up a new page (retrieving information from the system).

Comment: It doesn't matter if the page is private/protected. Post and Get are always used the same way. Post when you want to send data to a server. The server then does something with a data. Get when you want to retrieve data from the server and you do something with data.